# How to remove the vertical asymptote of the graph of tan(x)?

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

As the vertical asymptotes just add distraction to the graph, I want to remove them.

```
\documentclass[border=24pt,12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-3)(6.6,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-3)(6.5,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](0,-3)(6.28,3)}
        \psplot{0}{6.28}{tan(x)}
    \end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I don't want to invoke the `psplot` more than once. I know one solution by splitting the domain into several pieces but it is not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the option yMaxValue=4 to eliminate infinite values

```
\documentclass[border=24pt,12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-3)(6.6,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-3)(6.5,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none,linewidth=0](0,-3)(6.28,3)}
        \psplot[yMaxValue=4]{0}{6.28}{tan(x)}
    \end{psclip}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tangente]

Answer (score 1):

no need for clipping:

```
\documentclass[border=24pt,12pt,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-3)(6.6,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(0,-3)(6.5,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[yMaxValue=3,yMinValue=-3,plotpoints=5000]{0}{6.28}{tan(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]